# Applying Holo.Light theme to single controls

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to apply the Light theme to single controls? While using the standard Holo-Dark-theme, I want to do something like this:

```
<CheckBox style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.CompoundButton.CheckBox"></CheckBox>
```

But for some reason that doesn't work.

Comment: Please do not tag this with coding-style. Please see [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style) to see what coding style means.

Answer (score 2):

You can not apply a theme to a single control. Themes can only be applied to activites. You can apply a style to single control but this does not help in this case as you already noticed because the Widget.Holo.CompoundButton.CheckBox style does not add anything to the parent style Widget.CompoundButton.CheckBox.

Instead the whole styling takes place in the listChoiceIndicatorSingle selector of the current theme.

So your only choice is to replace this selector by your own as described e.g. here: [Setting Theme.Holo.Light changes everything except checkboxes in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7609810/setting-theme-holo-light-changes-everything-except-checkboxes-in-list)

Answer (score 0):

Read up on this page about [Styles and Themes in Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).  It goes over how to define which theme to use for a specific `Activity` or a whole `Application`.  You will also see how to customize themes and styles, and how to mix and match them.