# Setting Theme.Holo.Light changes everything except checkboxes in list

Tags: android, android-theme

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
```

I made my own theme and added a reference to it in my manifest. Everything looks perfect (buttons, textboxes etc) except for the checkboxes in my custom list.

```
    android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
```

The checkbox in my listitem is the default checkbox from Theme.Holo and I can't figure out why.

Grateful for any help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am having the same problem.  I have no idea why it isn't choosing the correct checkbox - you can barely see it on the light background.  For now, I copied the appropriate holo light checkbox images out the of the android drawable folders and into my project.  I then created my own   that referenced these images.  I then set the android:button attribute to my new selector xml.   My selector xml looks like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
                android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_focused_holo_light" /> 
        <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
                android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_focused_holo_light" />
        <item android:state_checked="false"
                android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_holo_light" />
        <item android:state_checked="true"
                android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_holo_light" />
</selector>
```

Make sure you copy all of the different density images (xhdpi, hdpi, etc.) into your project.

Comment: This solution helped with me! For some reason, which I have no idea why, my radio buttons do not have the default holo-light look. I copied the drawables for radio buttons instead of checkboxes.

Comment: if you don't have the required resources, download it from  http://android-holo-colors.com/

Answer (score 1):

The same thing happened to me but with radio buttons, as henry000 wrote.

I downloaded the original holo-light themed radiobuttons images and XML layouts from 
http://android-holo-colors.com/